Apache/PHP If index.php is not specified it's downloaded
I have upgraded from SLES 15 SP5 to SLES 15 SP6.
Each SP upgrade makes problems with Apache/PHP. Now again.
The current issue is that when the index.php is not specified the file is downloaded. Specifying the PHP script in the URL executes the PHP code.
sub.foo.com/ --> downloads the index.php
sub.foo.com/index.php --> Executes correctly the index.php
This means that Apache and PHP work properly but it doesn't somehow activate the PHP handler when index.php is NOT specified.
In the Apache log file is this entry:
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2537
httpd.conf has this directive:
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.html.var
There is no .htaccess file.
Before the upgrade everything was working properly. The upgrade must have modified something and since then I run into this issue.

PHP: 8.3.9
Apache:
Server version: Apache/2.4.58 (Linux/SUSE)  
Server built:   2024-07-17 04:55:34.000000000 +0000


What is the configuration?

It's an Apache bug:
https://www.cve.org/CVERecord?id=CVE-2024-40725
Description
A partial fix for  CVE-2024-39884 in the core of Apache HTTP Server 2.4.61 ignores some use of the legacy content-type based configuration of handlers. "AddType" and similar configuration, under some circumstances where files are requested indirectly, result in source code disclosure of local content. For example, PHP scripts may be served instead of interpreted. Users are recommended to upgrade to version 2.4.62, which fixes this issue.

UPDATE:
SUSE fixed it. Now it works properly. As already mentioned, the .conf files are correct.


This isn't the answer. Your config (.conf file) is wrong, which is why @symcbean asked for it.

There is a bug, which is unlikely to be your bug. This is a very common question. DirectoryIndex is irrelevant, so you clearly haven't read the docs. Do you have ScriptAlias? AddHandler? AddType? Any Options? Ask another question showing your config.

@QF0 The config files are OK. I have read the documentation, thank you very much for asking. I close now the topic. You apparently don't want to understand.

I had exactly the same problem. Chrome was constantly downloading the index.php. Curl and other browsers worked fine.
After installing HTTPS, the problem was solved

Unfortunately this is not the solution. Each client [Safari, Firefox, wget, curl, Edge] downloads the script. I don't understand what you mean with "installing HTTPS" in 2024.

Ok, It seems we have different problems. Mine arose when I updated Ubuntu, index.php also started downloading when the file name was not specified. Reinstalling php and apache did not help. The problem was only in chrome. I installed certbot and everything was solved
